# Is there any way to create a game level map in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an educational app and I'm asking if there is any way to create level map usign Flutter like the following examples
[level_map_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhCcF.jpg)
[level_map_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWFqr.jpg)

Note: I tried https://pub.dev/packages/game_levels_scrolling_map package but I couldn't do my custom level map like previous examples

Answer (score 0):

The answer is late but helpful for someone looking for it.
You can use [level_map](https://pub.dev/packages/level_map) package to create game level maps.